# Is it possible to run an Angular Admin template project in Ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

is it possible to run an Admin Angular template like this one https://fury.visurel.com/tables/all-in-one-table into a Ionic project for iOs and Android?

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible but there are also templates made also for ionic 
see more templates in this page
https://market.ionicframework.com/themes

if you use a normal template for ionic you cannot have best performances for mobile. ionic is like a web browser that runs your html/js files but if you use native directives it is fast as a real native mobile application

Comment: Thank you! I know there some good templates, but not as well as the one I linked to you! So do you confirm I can create a Ionic native app for iOs and Android?

Comment: @Ilovecoding yes I confirm it.

Comment: Could you please tell me/hint how to run an Angular Project into a ionic?

Comment: @Ilovecoding there is no simple way to convert into ionic project, you must migrate template file by file with all dependency. first of all try to understand what is a ionic framework and how it works, after this it will be very simple to migrate an exist angular project into ionic angular project